# Specify Google Play Store subscription offer with Flutter in_app_purchase package

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am implementing a discount system for subscriptions in my Flutter application, but I do not know how present different [Google Play Store subscription offers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973?hl=en) with the Flutter in_app_purchases package depending on whether or not a user has a coupon code.

How can I present a specific Google Play subscription offer to a user (different than just the base subscription plan) using Flutter's in_app_purchase package?

My understanding from the [in_app_purchase package docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase-library.html) is that I can pass the product ID of my subscription, but how can I pass in  specific subscription offer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been looking for the same thing, but apparently it is not yet supported by the flutter plugin. Google Play Offers are quite recent, maybe we will need to wait for a while before it is available.

I opened already an issue regarding this (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110909).

I will update this answer as soon as I have something new.

Comment: also commented there. Not too many ppl asked for this but I think it's a must